# solving log in iphone objective c calculations

Tags: iphone, logarithm

how can a logarithm be solved on the iphone. I tried using different methods with the log2f and all those however I wasnt sure exactly how to make a log lets say log (base4) 5 = x
and x would be given as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`log_a(x)=log_b(x) / log_b(a)`  where `a` is the base you want and `b` is any other base. In particular log base 4 of 5 is `log2f(5)/log2f(4)`